# 1200w dc-dc boost converter low voltage protection not working

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, buck-boost, undervoltage, over-discharge

I've purchased a 1200w dc-dc converter with the model number SZ-BT07CCCV.

I'm using it to convert 12v from a big battery to 24V.
the converter comes with three potentiometers according to the following image
[image]

now the converter works fine except for the most important feature for me which is the low voltage protection, I wanted to set the potentiometer of low battery voltage to around 11 volts to protect the battery from over-discharge and after adjusting it correctly and supplying the converter with less than 11volt then the Undervoltage led(labeled UVO) lights up but instead of the booster shutting down completely and cutting the power to the load it just shuts down the booster circuit and output the same voltage that is being supplied(11v), this is not good for my use case, and it will also not protect the battery.

My understanding of low voltage protection(over-discharge protection) is if the voltage is under a specific limit it cuts of the power to the load, not supply the load with that low voltage.
So is there something in particular wrong with my unit? or is this intended and by design? is it possible to modify the circuit somehow to achieve true over-discharge protection?

Comment: What does the manufacturer's datasheet say? Please provide a link to the datasheet.

Comment: That is typical, you need to pick the method of operation when you purchase the unit, not all are the same.

Comment: Boost converters pass the input voltage to the output when off, so yes that is probably intended.  You'll need to add a relay or FET if you need the outputs to be disconnected from the battery when off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this boost converter is designed to continue passing power, but you could easily add an undervoltage protection circuit that would completely disconnect the power source.

It could be as simple as a 12 volt DC relay in series with a 12 volt Zener diode, and a startup switch to bypass the diode, connected to the 24 VDC output. When starting, you'd need to hold the start switch, applying 12 VDC directly to the relay. Once 24 V is available, 12 volts would be dropped across the Zener, and the relay would have its rated 12 V. If the power falls back, the relay would drop out.

Another way to disconnect the battery would be to connect a relay from the battery positive to the boost output. While there's a 12 volt difference (i.e., the converter is boosting), the relay would be held closed. Again, some startup mechanism is needed.

You could also design or buy a circuit that auto-starts, without the switch, though requiring manual intervention could be an advantage for safety and to reduce the chance of battery discharge.